# Wordpress does not show products when the value of post_parent is not 0

Tags: plugins, api

I use [wp-e-commerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce/). I created a custom post type called "event". I would like to create new "event" as a parent and hook products under it. When I "hook" a product under post parent "event", wp-e-commenrce does not appear me this in products at the admin panel. The product exists on database and it's register. The only way to make this product visible is to set the value 0 to "post_parent" field on wp_post table. Wp-e-commerce by default give 0 to post_parent.

```
function createProduct($event_id, $attach_id, $attach)
        {
            // Create product object
            $product_name = get_the_title($event_id).'_'.$attach_id;
            $evman_product = array(
            'post_title'    => $product_name,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_type'     => 'wpsc-product',
            'post_parent'   => $event_id
            );

            // Insert the post into the database
            $this->unhookFromSavePost(); // see http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops
            $evman_the_product_id = wp_insert_post( $evman_product ); //get product's id 
            $this->hookToSavePost();
            //Re-attach attachment to new product
            $attach_duplicated = $attach;
            $attach_duplicated->post_parent = $evman_the_product_id;            
            $newAddedAttachment = wp_insert_attachment( $attach_dublicated );
            return evman_the_product_id;
        }
```

Comment: Why not make registrations a variation of an event product instead of trying to introduce a hierarchy the system wasn't designed for?

Comment: I want to leave the user to create an "event", upload the images of the product from media and wordpress make the product. Then I go to the event and see the products of the event.

Comment: @AndrewBartel Can I use variation instead of event (custom post type)?